Why is a texture distorted on the Quest and not in Editor?
I'm creating a VR app that plays 360º spherical panoramic videos into a sphere. The app is to run on quest2/3 but I'm having trouble getting the texture to show on the Quest exactly like it does on the editor. The following images display a crop of the 360 image on the editor (left picture) and on the quest (right picture).
Editor vs Quest 2
Why exactly is the image distorted on the quest? Does texture compression(ASTC, ETC2, etc) justify this? Is this actually a problem with how the mesh is loaded in the quest and how it would affect the UV mapping? Is this somehow related to the shader precision? Does anyone have any suggestion on what I can do to fix this?
The distortions are happening worse the closer you are to the poles of the sphere. Distortion happens at poles
I've played around with mesh import settings to see if I can make it be more precise with UVs. Turned off mesh compression and optimization. I've tried setting import setting to "calculate normals" and "import normals". I've altered the shader to be single precision from half precision. Nothing works.

I'm assuming there is floating point precision problems happening in the quest. the more stretched the polygon, the more distorted the picture was. So I used an icosphere instead to make sure all triangles as close to equal sided as possible.

And the distortion is gone.
